# Unable to marshal xml request with namespace

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, marshalling

I am using following code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(AFDType.class);

        AFDType AFDType = new AFDType();
        DeviceInfoType devInfoType = new DeviceInfoType();
        DeviceDetailInfoType devDetailInfoType = new DeviceDetailInfoType();

        devDetailInfoType.setEsnMeidDec("esn1234");
        devInfoType.setBrandCode("brand123");
        devInfoType.setSkuType("sku12345");
        devInfoType.setDeviceDetailInfo(devDetailInfoType);
        AFDType.setDeviceInfo(devInfoType);
        JAXBMarshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(AFDType, sw);
```

This generates an xml of following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:deviceInfo>
   <ns0:deviceDetailInfo>
      <esnMeidDec>esn1234</esnMeidDec>
   </ns0:deviceDetailInfo>
   <ns0:brandCode>brand123</ns0:brandCode>
   <ns0:skuType>sku12345</ns0:skuType>
</ns0:deviceInfo>
```

However i require following xml:

```
<ns0:addFD xmlns:ns0="http://ee.abc.com/interfaces/afd/v1/afd.xsd">
         <ns0:deviceInfo>
            <ns0:deviceDetailInfo>
               <ns0:esnMeidHex>36748298746378</ns0:esnMeidHex>
            </ns0:deviceDetailInfo>
            <ns0:brandCode>SPR</ns0:brandCode>
            <ns0:skuType>BYO</ns0:skuType>
         </ns0:deviceInfo>
      </ns0:addFD>
```

Can someone please help me how to obtain the 2nd xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `package-info.java` into `interfaces.afd` root folder with the following content

```
@XmlSchema(
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    namespace="http://ee.abc.com/interfaces/afd/v1",
    xmlns={@XmlNs(prefix="ns0",
                  namespaceURI="http://ee.abc.com/interfaces/afd/v1")}
)
package interfaces.afd;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

[Read more about it here.](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes)

The enclosing root element `<ns0:addFd></ns0:addFd>` can be achieved by adding `@XmlRootElement(name = "addFd")` tag above the AddFd.class like below :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "addFd")
public class AddFd {
..
}
```

Comment: I added your code , the obtained xml is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns3:deviceInfo> <ns3:deviceDetailInfo> <ns3:esnMeidDec>esn4</ns3:esnMeidDec> </ns3:deviceDetailInfo> <ns3:brandCode>bran</ns3:brandCode> <ns3:skuType>sku12345</ns3:skuType> </ns3:deviceInfo> ` but i need xml as `<ns0:addFD xmlns:ns0="http://ee.abc.com/interfaces/afd/v1/afd.xsd"> <ns0:deviceInfo> <ns0:deviceDetailInfo> <ns0:esnMeidHex>3</ns0:esnMeidHex> </ns0:deviceDetailInfo> <ns0:brandCode>SPR</ns0:brandCode> <ns0:skuType>B</ns0:skuType> </ns0:deviceInfo> </ns0:addFD>`

Comment: The outer hierarchy of `<ns0:addFD xmlns:ns0="http://ee.abc.com/interfaces/afd/v1/afd.xsd"> </ns0:addFD>` is missing, how can i make sure it also comes..